# Cargar Archivos en Servidor FTPS desde Java

Tags: java, netbeans

y gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Cómo lo menciono en el título, estoy intentando subir archivos a un servidor FTPS desde NetBeans 13. Ya hago la conexión, accedo a las carpetas vía código pero a la hora de subir el archivo no ocurre absolutamente nada ni tampoco el IDE me envía algún error.

Alguno de ustedes, lo ha logrado hacer? Hay algunas librerías en específico que sean las adecuadas? Y ojo al dato, el proveedor de mi alojamiento solo admite conexiones FTPS y no FTP o SFTP.

Comment: Has el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example]. Ayúdanos a ayudarte por favor!

Answer (score 0):

yo he logrado hacer la conexión usando la librería

`org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient`

La connexion esta ok la hago usando:

`FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("SSL", true);`
`ftpClient.connect(host, puerto);`
`ftpClient.login(user, password);`

Con `ftpClient.isConnected()` valido que haya conexión.

El problema lo tengo cuando intento colocar archivos usando:

`ftpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), fis)` donde fis es el nombre con el que guardo el archivo, me esta devolviendo el error: 501 Server cannot accept argument. entonces ahi no se que es lo que esta pasando.

Si encontraste algo mas, quedo muy atento.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/369995)